# How to rename a develop branch to master in github

Tags: github

I have an interesting scenario.
One of my fellow developers created a develop branch in local and pushed to github repo. The current state of the repo is there is no Master but with only Develop branch. I want to fix this by having a Master and let Develop branch out of Master , how can i do this in github
One scenario is renaming Develop branch to Master
Other way is to recreate the entire repo with Master and copy code from old repo

Answer (score 0):

> The current state is there is no Master

So create the master branch from develop and push.

```
git checkout -b master
git push -u origin --all
```

Comment: but how can develop become child of master, or they both isolated branches by themselves